# Asp.Net MVC Routing Concept

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I am having an issue while dealing with routing in MVC.

I have defined the following routes in Route.Config

```
  routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Test",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{param}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "FirstAction" }
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Testy",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{secondparm}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "SecondAction" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
          name: "Test2",
          url: "{controller}/{action}/{encodedparam}",
          defaults: new { controller = "User", action = "UserInfo" }
      );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Problem is that the first route is working fine but in second and third I got null values for the respective parameter.

Did I miss something?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You must match the parameter name for the third. If you write :

{id}

You must write

> public ActionResult AnyAction(int **id**)

id could be of any type

i think there is conflict beetween your routes. You need only this mapping :

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",                                              // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }  // Parameter defaults
        );
```

if you need custom routing for other elements don't put `"{controller}/{action}/..."` inside, because he will take the first route config that is matching with.
You can call all your routes precising the name of your parameter if its different from "id" :

```
http://localhost/home/firstaction?param=123
http://localhost/home/secondaction?secondparam=123
http://localhost/user/userinfo?encodedparam=123
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I didn't get my answer.

Comment: can you gives us your code corresponding controller action ?

Comment: ya sure,                                                                                                                 
       public ActionResult SecondAction(string secondparm)
        {
             return View();
        }

        public ActionResult FirstAction(string param)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "My page.";

            return View("Contact");
        }

Comment: http://localhost:portnumber/home/secondaction/value  --> unable to get parameter value in action method                                                             http://localhost:portnumber/home/firstaction/value   --> this is working fine and I got the parameter value in the action method                                                                                http://localhost:portnumber/user/userinfo/value --> unable to get parameter value in action method

Comment: Hii @Orkad I have gone through your response, it looks cool can you explain the reason for this behavior of routing?

Comment: You have to call `SecondAction` in this way => localhost:portnumber/home/secondaction?secondparm=yourID. And change parameet type from `string` to `int`.

Comment: Hi @AmanSoni ! in you cases you only need the generic "Default" route template as described above. you can call your other routes like this : http://localhost/user/userinfo?encodedparam=123 and it will work. I will edit my answer to make it clear for all your cases. If it resolve your problem you can accept the answer to close the subjet ! have a good day ! :)

Comment: Hii @Sh.Imran I don't want to do that, that's why I have defined my routes!!

Comment: Hi @Orkad thanks for your time, but i don't want to call my action in that way http://localhost/home/firstaction?param=123. I just want to use localhost:portnumber/home/secondaction/value. I appreciate your response!!

Comment: @AmanSoni Why you don't want. Better approach is to define default route as generically which is simple and clean. If you want this, I can explain it to you further.

Answer (score 0):

As you want to use the URL in such way: `localhost:portnumber/home/secondaction/value` instead of `localhost:portnumber/home/secondaction?secondparam=value`.

You have to follow the below approach, which would behave as generic for all your Action Methods, whether they are containing parameters or not.

- Declare default route in RouterConfig.cs as:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

- Then Parameter name in method must be same as in default route:

```
public ActionResult SecondAction(string id)
{ 
    return View(); 
}
```

- Paramter type could be any type.

In this way you do not need to declare other routes.

Comment: @Aman was it helpful? your problem is solved or not?